# Configure and use push notifications for IOS - Xamarin

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin.ios, sharepoint-2013, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to configure and use push notifications in SharePoint 2013 apps for **iPhone Xamarin.**

Recently I started creating a Xamarin application that supports both Android and IPhone application. So my doubt here is, Is it possible to create a solution in **SharePoint Server** for sending push notifications and a **client side iOS - Xamarin** application for receiving the notifications.

If Possible how I can create the same. Please help. If it is not possible anyone please suggest me a workaround to implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider your mobile applications and your backend different concerns. For your apps it does not matter what is running in the backend.

But what matters is that each of the platforms has its own notification system, see:

- Android: [An Overview of Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/)
- iOS: [Push Notifications in iOS](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/remote_notifications_in_ios/)

Beside the platform-spefific configuration of certificates etc

Comment: I am also trying similar thing any comment on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127558/sharepoint-push-notification-service-for-iphone

Comment: Not much to add to my answer here, it's the same scenario I think. Find the place within SharePoint where new notifications are triggered and send them over to your app with PushSharp.